# Splitting the column to multiple columns

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT
    STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(TimeStamp,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") AS TimeStamp,
    Value.provided,
    __key__.app AS ProjectID,
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(__key__.path, r'"hostname"[, ]*"(.*?)"') AS hostname,
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(__key__.path, r'"machine"[, ]*"(.*?)"') AS machine,
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(__key__.path, r'"variable"[, ]*"(.*?)"') AS variable,
    IF(value.provided = 'integer', CAST(value.integer AS STRING),              
    CAST(value.boolean AS STRING)) AS value
FROM 
    [spark-test-project-152415:spark_machine_learning.spark_12272016]
ORDER BY 
    TimeStamp
LIMIT 100000
```

The above query extracts a Dataset as in the attached picture. I need to split a variable column into multiple columns with values under it. I think it must be done using a sub-query. How can I get this started?

[image]

Expected output:

[image: expected output]
Query with PIVOT

`SELECT
  *
FROM (SELECT
    #Timestamp,
    STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(TimeStamp,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") AS [TimeStamp],
    Value.provided,
    __key__.app AS ProjectID,
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(__key__.path, r'"hostname"[, ]*"(.*?)"') AS [hostname],
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(__key__.path, r'"machine"[, ]*"(.*?)"') AS [machine],
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(__key__.path, r'"variable"[, ]*"(.*?)"') AS [variable],
    IF(value.provided = 'integer', CAST(value.integer AS STRING), CAST(value.boolean AS STRING)) AS [value]
  FROM
    [spark-test-project-152415:spark_machine_learning.spark_12272016]
  ORDER BY
    TimeStamp ) AS SourceTable PIVOT ([value] FOR [variable] IN ([Counter_Strokes_No_Reset],
      [Press_State_Code],
      [Press_Operator_1],
      [Press_Stop_Time_Limit],
      [Counter_Good_Parts_No_Reset],
      [Press_Error_Reason_Code],
      [Counter_Scrap_No_Reset],
      [Production_Tool_Number],
      [Press_Stop_Time_Actual],
      [Production_Good_Parts_Preset],
      [Press_Shaft_Speed],
      [Production_Part_Number],
      [Press_Total_Tonnage],
      [Production_Job_Number]) ) AS PivotTable`

Comment: from what I understand the image shows your current output. can you provide example of expected output!

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xa1hg.png

Comment: @Mikhail, I would likt to get something like the one attached in the above link

Comment: there are plenty posts on this subject here on SO. have you even tied to do any search?

Comment: @Mikhail, Yes I did but I could not get the the Alternative for PIVOT Command, This is the query I have now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I get this started?

Try below, it might give you an idea

```
SELECT
  [TimeStamp],
  Value_Provided,
  ProjectID,
  hostname,
  machine,
  SUM(CASE WHEN variable = 'Counter_Strokes_No_Reset' THEN value.integer END) AS Counter_Strokes_No_Reset,
  SUM(CASE WHEN variable = 'Press_State_Code' THEN value.integer END) AS Press_State_Code,
  SUM(CASE WHEN variable = 'Press_Operator_1' THEN value.integer END) AS Press_Operator_1,
  SUM(CASE WHEN variable = 'Press_Stop_Time_Limit' THEN value.integer END) AS Press_Stop_Time_Limit,
  SUM(CASE WHEN variable = 'Counter_Good_Parts_No_Reset' THEN value.integer END) AS Counter_Good_Parts_No_Reset,
  SUM(CASE WHEN variable = 'Press_Error_Reason_Code' THEN value.integer END) AS Press_Error_Reason_Code,
  SUM(CASE WHEN variable = 'Counter_Scrap_No_Reset' THEN value.integer END) AS Counter_Scrap_No_Reset,
  SUM(CASE WHEN variable = 'Production_Tool_Number' THEN value.integer END) AS Production_Tool_Number,
  SUM(CASE WHEN variable = 'Press_Stop_Time_Actual' THEN value.integer END) AS Press_Stop_Time_Actual,
  SUM(CASE WHEN variable = 'Production_Good_Parts_Preset' THEN value.integer END) AS Production_Good_Parts_Preset,
  SUM(CASE WHEN variable = 'Press_Shaft_Speed' THEN value.integer END) AS Press_Shaft_Speed,
  SUM(CASE WHEN variable = 'Production_Part_Number' THEN value.integer END) AS Production_Part_Number,
  SUM(CASE WHEN variable = 'Press_Total_Tonnage' THEN value.integer END) AS Press_Total_Tonnage,
  SUM(CASE WHEN variable = 'Production_Job_Number' THEN value.integer END) AS Production_Job_Number
FROM (
  SELECT
    STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(TIMESTAMP,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") AS [TimeStamp],
    Value.provided AS Value_Provided,
    __key__.app AS ProjectID,
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(__key__.path, r'"hostname"[, ]*"(.*?)"') AS [hostname],
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(__key__.path, r'"machine"[, ]*"(.*?)"') AS [machine],
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(__key__.path, r'"variable"[, ]*"(.*?)"') AS [variable],
    IF(value.provided = 'integer', CAST(value.integer AS INTEGER), CAST(value.boolean AS INTEGER)) AS [value]
  FROM [spark-test-project-152415:spark_machine_learning.spark_12272016]
) 
GROUP BY [TimeStamp], Value_Provided, ProjectID, hostname, machine
ORDER BY [TimeStamp]
```

Comment: Thank you @Mikhail was able to get the desired output